# Cron Job and phpAdmin Trigger to remove data

Tags: php, cron

I have tried cron jobs and triggers to remove data after a given time but no luck i have a TIMESTAMP in my table called timer.

Here is the code that have i tried.

**Code i tried for the trigger**

```
DELETE FROM wp_wpgmza WHERE timer <= NOW()
```

**Code i tried for Cron Jobs**

**dbonnect.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "----";
$username = "----";
$password = "----";
$dbname = "-----";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "Connected successfully";

?>


</body>
</html>
```

**cronjobcommand.php**

```
<?php 

     include('dbconnect.php');

     mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_wpgmza WHERE timer < NOW()");

    ?>
```

**Cron Jobs Command**

```
/path/cronjobcommand.php
```

Comment: ... `php /path/cronjobcommand.php`

Comment: Just a suggestion, You can also use Mysql scheduled events